# Access Account Information on the Device using JavaScript sdk

Tags: javascript, android, facebook, authentication, account-kit

I am using JavaScript sdk of Account-Kit but unable to get the phone-number in the response packet
Please find relevant link for this:-
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/accountkit/webjs/reference

```
function loginCallback(response) {
console.log(response.status);
console.log(response.code);
console.log(response.state);

/* Not able to get user account information 
  if (response.status === "PARTIALLY_AUTHENTICATED") {
    // Send code to server to exchange for access token
  }
  else if (response.status === "NOT_AUTHENTICATED") {
    // handle authentication failure

  }
  else if (response.status === "BAD_PARAMS") {
    // handle bad parameters
  }
}
```

There is a function written for Android to Access Account Information on the Device but I didn't find for the web in javascript.

Comment: you can´t get the phone number with the facebook api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AccountKit JS SDK returns an authorization code after successful login that you need to exchange for an access token. After you have this access token you can hit the '/me' endpoint to get the phone number.

See:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/accountkit/accesstokens
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/accountkit/webjs#examplenodejs